# Failed OAuth Authentication to Twitter API

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

I understand authentication requirements for accessing the Twitter API have recently changed.  The following code results in: Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to api.twitter.com port 443: Timed out

Related answers' suggested code has been used.  Wondering if they address the API access requirements changes.

```
library(twitteR)
library(devtools)
library(ROAuth)
library(RCurl)

download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",
          destfile="cacert.pem")

requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumerSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                         consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                         requestURL=requestURL,
                         accessURL=accessURL,
                         authURL=authURL)

twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

Thanks.

Comment: When has API changed? Last change to `twitter` package was in July of 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is a proxy server getting in my way.  Running this code outside the LAN environment works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

currently

```
>      api_key <- "-redacted-" 
>      api_secret <- "-redacted-"
>      access_token <-"-redacted-"
>      access_token_secret <- "-redacted-"

setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
```

is in vogue.

Should you encounter any errors , 
please go ahead with

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key='your key' , consumer_secret= 'your secret ')
```

this should open up browser authentication.
Hope it helps! 
Thanks